# FTP Transfer Types for PHP files - Is binary transfer okay for PHP files?

Tags: php, ftp, binary, ascii, transfer

(I have a Linux server and My computer's operating sysyem is Windows.)

Hi. I've heard that you should transfer text files like PHP files via ASCII transfer type, and for other types of files such as images, you should use binary transfer type. Otherwise you can get errors.

But I had once encountered with an error after I transferred some PHP files through ASCII transfer mode. So I tried binary transfer instead then it resolved the problem right away.

Being curious, I downloaded some PHP files and uploaded them again using Filezilla. (both time through binary transfer) And they caused no problems at all.

Question :
Was I just lucky or is it totally okay to transfer PHP files using binary transfer mode?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't filezilla have an auto mode anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use binary transfer any time; it transfers a byte-for-byte identical copy. You should use ASCII for all text-based files.

You state you "had a problem" uploading a PHP script using ASCII, but I find it hard to believe that was the cause. Can you elaborate?